# Is it possible make installer for modified and builed by me .net sources?

Tags: .net, installation, runtime

I'm searching a lot to right answer. Let me descript the problem.

I've downloaded: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime and build it on Windows using build.cmd. This take me much time. Ok I have got compiled sources. But how can I install the new (possible modified by me version) runtime on target system. The installer I think should register .net runtime and copy it to proper location. I need possibility to choose the new .net runtime in Visual Studio project settings. This have possitive for better debugging. Mayby I need some other .net source projects: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk, https://github.com/dotnet/installer ?